# Autocomplete jcombobox javanetbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, autocomplete, jcombobox

I am trying to implement autocomplete on my combobox but It says cannot find symbol. Are there any classes I need to import for this method to work? I have already imported javax.swing.*;

Method:

```
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(mycombobox);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AutoCompleteDecorator` is not part of the standard Java SE distribution, it is part of the `SwingX` project.

If `SwingX` is already in your classpath, you can just import the `AutoCompleteDecorator` with

```
import org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.AutoCompleteDecorator;
```

Comment: Thanks. I added the swingx library to my project and the import finally worked